# Classifier extraction from MLSeq R package

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I'm currently reasonably new to R and am having trouble extracting the information I would like from a package.

I am using `MLSeq` to implement Random Forest on RNA Seq data to find biomarkers for a condition. Currently, the output given by default is just how well it classified the data and a table that describes actual class against predicted class.

What I want is the importance of each feature so that i can take the highest ranking features and continue to investigate those.

Does anyone have experience with MLSeq package or know of a similar machine learning package that has this functionality?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You need to give more detail on the problem you're having.  Any code/examples you can post that are not working for you?

Comment: The code is working but it's hard to give an example. The MLSeq manual doesn't detail this issue and its just the manuals code with my data at this point.
http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/MLSeq/inst/doc/MLSeq.pdf
Pg 8, the top section is the output i currently have. There is a object class called "MLSeq class", as seen on pg 7 they denote a variable "rf", within that object I want to know what features best classified the data and use these as potential biomarkers.  There is a huge amount of data within the object and Im struggling to find what I want, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret package has a very useful function called varImp. If you don't have a very large number of predictors you could use it to get/plot their importance.
In your case, let's suppose you have trained your model:

```
# training
svm = classify(data = data.trainS4, method = "svm", normalize = "deseq",    deseqTransform = "voom", cv = 3, rpt = 3, ref = "PP")
```

you can get the variable importance of your predictors using the following command:

```
VI <- varImp(svm@trained)
```

However, before doing that, read carefully how `varImp()` works